# array of objects where constructor has an argument

Tags: c++

I want to have an array of objects.
Each object has a constructor with one argument. 
My object array initialisation :

```
set s[]=new set[n]; // creates an array of n objects of class set
```

However, it says that I cannot do so, because my constructor requires an argument.
My Constructor:

```
set(int size){}
```

I've understood the problem, but cant think of a good solution. 
What I can do, is either initialise each object seperately :

```
set s1(size);
set s2(size); //& so on.....
```

or remove the argument from constructor......both solutions are not quite satisfactory

Can anyone help me out to find a better solution to this ?

Note: 'size' value of each object is different/dynamic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<set> s(n, set(x,y,z));
```

This will create a vector (a dynamically resizeable array) of n `set` objects, each a copy of `set(x,y,z)`.  If you want to use different constructors for various elements, or the same constructor with different arguments:

```
std::vector<set> s;      // create empty vector
s.push_back(set(x,y,z));
s.push_back(set(y,z,x));
...
... // repeat until s.size() == n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a different constructor that takes no arguments and initializes the values, and then set the values of each variable in a loop

```
set() {
    this.size = 0;
}
```

and then in a for loop initialize each element with the desired `size`, using direct binding or a getter/setter functions.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    s[i].size = value[i]; // or create a setter function
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I had the same thing in mind earlier, but I specifically wanted to initialise it using constructor. 
Thanks for the effort.